# How do I get original selector using jQuery's on() function with a filter?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's `.on()` function to attach some behavior on the `click` event on an object, say a `span`.

My setup looks something like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'span', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Inside this function, `this` is `span`.  **How do I get `#container`?**

---

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/Nk3p9/

```
<div id="container">
    <span>Click Me!</span>
</div>​
```

--

```
$('#container').on('click', 'span', function() {

    var span = $(this),
        div  = false; // This is what I need

    console.log(span);
});​
```

Comment: An ID can only appear once, so ... `$('#container')`. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/)

```
$('#container').on('click', 'span', function(e) {

    var span = $(this),
    div  = e.delegateTarget;

    console.log(div);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/Nk3p9/2/)

Comment: I love when someone pwns a bunch of 'not possible' answers like that.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would just be to use `span.parent()`.

Comment: What if the container is an ancestor?

Comment: Easier than `$('#container')`?  Hehe.

Comment: @mootinator maybe/maybe not, but it's fewer characters.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin then no, there is no simple way to do it without knowing more information about the parent.